# Illegal string offset while trying print the value with in the array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am rendering view in mail template but in my view I am getting following error when I use `dd($row['product_name']);`. I get product name but not in following code don't know meaning of this error:

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row['product_name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row['amount'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row['quantity'] }}</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

getting error:

> Illegal string offset 'product_name'

Comment: It may seem like a silly question, but do ALL occurances of that array have a `product_name` occurance? Do a `print_r($order)` to check

Comment: print_r($order) and post result here

Comment: can you show me the controller and model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$order is an object `$row->product_name` and not an array `$row['product_name']`.

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of 'product_name' key is not exist in your array element. Before using it, check is that key exist in that array element with `isset`

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ isset($row['product_name'])?$row['product_name']:'' }}</td>

        </tr> @endforeach
```

Comment: when i {{ $row->product_name }} i am getting error like Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>

        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Check out the laravel documentation for blade https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: A description of WHY would make this into a much better answer

Comment: How did you know he is iterating over model not on array?

Comment: when i {{ $row->product_name }} i am getting error like Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this solution

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>

        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: A description of WHY would make this into a much better answer

Comment: How did you know he is iterating over model not on array?

Comment: when i {{ $row->product_name }} i am getting error like Trying to get property 'product_name' of non-object

Answer (score 1):

add **dd($row)** insted of dd($row['product_name']).

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller returns Object not Array so you try like that

```html
@foreach ($order as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

$order is an object you can not use it like an array

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want to to use the record like this then you need to convert the object [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)

```
$order =  $order->toArray();
```

After that you can use like this: `$row['product_name']`

Answer (score 1):

here $order is an object so you cant use like $row['product_name'].you can use the property of an object using -> operator. so try like this

```
@foreach ($order as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->product_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->quantity }}</td>

        </tr>
@endforeach
```